# jwt auth doesn't work for other controllers in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

Laravel web auth was working well.
I'm trying to use jwt-auth module.
Here's my code with jwt-auth module

```
---authcontroller.php
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // return response()->json($validator->errors(), 200);
            session()->flash('error', json_encode($validator->errors()));
            return back()->withInput();
        }
        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            // return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 200);
            session()->flash('error', 'These credentials do not match.');
            return back()->withInput();
        }
        //////// this is test code
        echo auth()->check();
        //////////////////
        $response_token = $this->createNewToken($token);
        session()->flash('token', $response_token);
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

---web.php

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

],
    function ($router) {
        Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
        Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
        Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
        Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
        Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);
    }
);
---auth.php

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

The problem is *test code returns true, but in the redirection controller, auth()->check() returns false.
i.e. auth()->check() returns true only when login controller, but returns false for other controllers

What's the problem?

---updates (redirection page code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>@yield('title')</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />



        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.7.0/dist/alpine.js" defer></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        @yield('extra-css')
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/blue-logo.png')}}"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('audition') }}">Audition</a>
                <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('about') }}">About</a>
                <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('playing') }}">Playing</a>
                <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('faq') }}">Faq</a>
                @if(!auth('api')->check())
                    <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
                    <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('userType') }}">Register</a>
                @else
                    <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('support') }}">Support</a>
                    <a class="mr-3" href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a>
                    <form class="d-inline-block" method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <a class="mr-3" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.closest('form').submit();">Logout</a>
                    </form>
                @endif
            </div>
        </header>
        @yield('content')
        <footer id="footer">
            <ul class="icons">
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-github"><span class="label">GitHub</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="copyright">
                <li>&copy; Untitled.</li><li>Credits: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
        @yield('extra-js')
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `auth('api')` hence `auth('api')->check()`

`auth()` helper function by default returns the authenticated user and stores it in session and cookie for jwt or any other api authenitcation methods use `auth('api')` which is gonna check the `Bearer` token and if the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: Thank you Arman.
I tried with auth('api') but it is still false on landing page(redirection page) after login action.
I added redirection page code.